# Como podria salvar $i en secuencia de numeros para obtener un rango de colores en bash

Tags: bash, bucles

¿Cómo podria lograr que se imprima una secuencia de números para no tener que escribirla a mano desde el número 1 hasta el 255 en `\e[38:5:[aqui]m`?

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(seq 1 255);
do;
    echo "\e[38:5:$im texto en color\e[0m";
done
```

Ejemplo de como deberia quedar para que se imprima el texto de un color diferente en cada número

```
echo -e "\e[38:5:1m texto en color\e[0m"
echo -e "\e[38:5:2m texto en color\e[0m"
echo -e "\e[38:5:3m texto en color\e[0m"
echo -e "\e[38:5:255m texto en color\e[0m"
```

Answer (score 2):

No se si te refieres a como escapar una variable en una instrucción de este tipo, donde debes unir una cadena a la variable, pero casi lo tenias si lo hubieras escrito así dentro del bucle:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(seq 1 255);
do
    echo -e "\e[38:5:""$i""m texto en color\e[0m";
done
```

### Cambios realizados:

1. He quitado el punto y coma final (**;**) del **do**, porque daba un error de sintaxis.
2. He agregado el parámetro **-e** al `echo` para habilitar la interpretación de las barras invertidas.
3. He dividido la cadena completa en tres consecutivas, para separar la **m** de la variable y que no se confundiera el interprete.

Tambien funcionaria solo con unas comillas dobles, es decir, dejando a la variable a la intemperie en la cadena (**mala práctica**):

```
echo -e "\e[38:5:"$i"m texto en color\e[0m";
```

pero entonces dejaríamos la variable sin entrecomillar, y eso [podria provocar otro tipo de errores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else).

Se recomienda que las variables vayan [siempre entrecomilladas](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2086) para evitar problemas con la división de palabras y la [expansión de nombre de archivo](https://www.oulub.com/es-ES/Shell/globbingref.html#FTN.AEN17572) (globbing), con algunas [pocas excepciones](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2086#exceptions).

Puedes comprobar tu código en este [testeador](https://www.shellcheck.net/) de scripts de shell.

Comment: muchas gracias, me funciono bien y la informacion que me dejaste me sirvio.

Comment: @testteste me alegro que te haya servido :-). Deberias marcar como aceptada la respuesta que finalmente haya solucionado mejor tu problema, para no dejar la pregunta pendiente eternamente. Para aprender a aceptar respuestas mírate este [enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200) y para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio haz el [tour], que son 2 minutos, y así entenderas el porque es importante aceptarlas para que el resto de la comunidad encuentre mejor las buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar:

```
printf '\e[38:5:%sm texto en color\e[0m\n' {1..255}
```

Basicamente imprime la cadena que planteas sustituyendo los valores de `%s` con los números de 1 a 255.

Alternativamente usando tu código, simplemente encierra la `i` entre `{}`:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(seq 1 255);
do
    echo "\e[38:5:${i}m texto en color\e[0m";
done
```

Comment: gracias, trate de salvar la variable, de muchas formas pero lo hacia junto con signo de dolar y no funcionaba, ademas la solucion que planteas se me hace elegante porque es en una sola linea de codigo